# How to set gop-size on NVenc(HEVC) with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, hevc, nvenc

I want to set gop size on NVenc(HEVC) with ffmpeg, but what I did is all failed:

```
-keyiny 60 or -gop-len 60 or -gop-length 60
```

The command I set is as follows:

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel cuvid -r 50 -i BasketballDrive_1920x1080_50.ts -c:v hevc_nvenc -preset medium -rc vbr -b:v 2M test_2M.265
```

The default gop-size seems to be 250.

If anyone have some suggestions? Or it cannot set gop-size by command?

Answer (score 3):

It's `-g`

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel cuvid -r 50 -i BasketballDrive_1920x1080_50.ts -g 60 -c:v hevc_nvenc -preset medium -rc vbr -b:v 2M test_2M.265
```